# How can I fix my x-axis, and plot my dates using GGPlot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have a CSV file with two columns. Date (DD-MM-YYYY) and Gas Price (0.00).  I also converted the date using as.Date. But when I attempted to plot it using ggplot, I kept getting this error that it can't work with numeric type or something.

**Here is my source code:**

```
gasoline <- read.csv(file.choose()) 
Date <- gasoline$Date 
Price <- as.numeric(gasoline$Price) str(Price) ggplot(gasoline, aes(Date, Price)) + geom_line(colour="red")
```

**Unfortunately, this code results in my graph having every date crammed down at the bottom so that it is barely legible:**

[image: R output]

(imgur.com/a/iitXw). 
It's just a flat line. It also says, "geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?"

How can I plot dates such as this in Ggplot?

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to diagnose the problem or propose a solution without your code or data. However, the code below is a very simple way to create a basic plot from example data that matches your description of your data:

```
# attach the ggplot package
library(ggplot2)

# make example data that matches your description
# (where the dates are January, April, July, and October 1 of 2015)
dates <- c('01-01-2015', '01-04-2015', '01-07-2015', '01-10-2015')
prices <- rnorm(4, 3)

# now convert dates to date format
dates <- as.Date(dates, format='%d-%m-%Y')

# you should then be able to create a simple plot using qplot
qplot(dates, prices, geom='line', xlab='Date', ylab='Price',
      main='Gas Prices Over Time')
```

Note the use of the format option in the `as.Date()` function. Since the dates are in DD-MM-YYYY format, while `as.Date()` assumes YYYY-MM-DD format, your dates would not convert correctly without that option:

```
dates <- c('01-01-2015', '01-04-2015', '01-07-2015', '01-10-2015')
dates <- as.Date(dates)
format(dates, format="%B %d %Y")
[1] "January 20 1" "April 20 1"   "July 20 1"    "October 20 1"
```

Since you had some problem with your dates being numeric, I suspect you did some data cleaning after converting them to dates; for example,

```
dates <- c('01-01-2015', '01-04-2015', '01-07-2015', '01-10-2015', NA)
dates <- as.Date(dates, format='%d-%m-%Y')
class(dates)
[1] "Date"
dates <- ifelse(is.na(dates), NA, dates)
class(dates)
[1] "numeric"
```

This is because Date objects are stored as integer values, which are used when making logical comparisons [(see this page at IDRE)](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-does-r-handle-date-values/). However, that still should not throw an error when plotting; the axis labels should simply be numbers rather than dates.

```
prices <- c(rnorm(4, 3), NA)
qplot(dates, prices, geom='line', xlab='Date', ylab='Price',
      main='Gas Prices Over Time')
```

Hopefully this will get you started on a solution to your problem.

EDIT:

Having seen the first twelve rows of your csv file, I can give you the following solution:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- read.csv('dataframe.csv') # change file name/path as appropriate
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format='%m/%d/%Y')
ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, y=Price)) + geom_line(color="red")
```

For me this produced the following plot:

[image: Gas Prices Plot]

I believe the issue was that in the code you provided me, the date variable was not converted to a date object; it was a factor (as seen in the lower right of the screenshot you provided). There was only one observation per level of the factor, resulting in the error you saw. You can get rid of that error by adding `group=1` to the aesthetic (i.e. `aes(x=Date, y=Price, group=1)`), but this does not accomplish exactly what you want.

The key is making sure you convert the variable to a `Date` object (being careful about the format, as mentioned above); then everything works out nicely.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the screenshots you linked.

Comment: Updated my original post so that it is now framed into a much more understandable question